# Android Firebase Push Notification Icon is not showing only in Pixel devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tested this with Pixel XL and Pixel 2 devices.
Push Notification Icon is not showing in these Android devices. Instead of a app icon it shows a just a grey box.

So is there a way to show app icon in those devices for notifications?

Here is the Code:

```
String CHANNEL_ID =   "channel_01";
// Get notification manager
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Build the notification
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    /* Create or update. */
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
        message,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setTicker(message);
}else{
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setTicker(message);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have provided the code. Thank you!

Comment: On other devices, works well?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes . Issue is only in Pixel devices. Notification icon is visible as a  grey box in pixel devices.

Comment: @AlexMamo Any Update?